# Run Codeigniter URL in background

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

In my codeigniter project an excel file around 5000 records uploaded and updated in database, when doing this action it taken around 15 minutes to complete. Please give me any idea to run this task in background , because of this the user no need to wait until it complete the update queries.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about anything like Jobs or a Scheduler for codeigniter.

For your specific use case you could also look into PHP Generators.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php

Generators can probably speed up the task you talk about significantly.